# Compile single app packages for cyanogenmod in windows

Tags: android, eclipse, compilation, mingw, cyanogenmod

I want to modify the phone.apk and someone said it's easy to do with cyanogenmod.

Because I can't compile a single package in Eclipse (a lot of missing constants), I figured out I need to compile it with MinGW (cross-compiling) and also the whole rom source.

Has anybody done this before ?

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

At the moment windows compiling is not supported, so i will just virtualize a linux OS with VirtualBox for compiling purpose.